# Overlay widget panel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, canvas, grid

I'm trying to display a set of controls as an 'overlay widget panel' above a fixed control. My first idea was to use a `ItemsControl` where the `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` contains a `Canvas` element.

Example:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Widgets}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=(widgets:IWidget.Top)}" />
                ...
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
           ...
```

This works fine, however one huge drawback for me is that the positioning must be set absolutely through `Canvas.Left`, `Canvas.Top` etc., where I would prefer some kind of "docking" (e.g. TopLeft, TopCenter, TopRight etc.) Are there any other ways or maybe even a built-in way to do this?

Comment: DockPanel may be? [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx) about containers.

Comment: @ZloyMakak DockPanel unfortunately is not aware of any ZIndex for overlaying the controls.

Comment: try using simple Grid